# Link JavaScript object within HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

How would I be able to pull the data from the JS script within my HTML? I am wanting to pull the "Title", "Description", and "Link" objects and display them within my HTML code.

Here is the code:

```html
<div class="roadMap" id="roadMap"></div>

<script src="/siteassets/bootstrap3/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="/publiccdnlib/PnP-JS-Core/pnp.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/publiccdnlib/es6-Promise/es6-promise.auto.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/publiccdnlib/fetch/fetch.min.js"></script>
<script src="/publiccdnlib/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
<script src="/publiccdnlib/CommonJS/CommonJS.js"></script>
<script src="/publiccdnlib/knockout/knockout.js"></script>
<script src="/publiccdnlib/knockout/knockout.simpleGrid.3.0.js"></script>
<script src="/publiccdnlib/toastr/toastr.min.js"></script>
<script src="/publiccdnlib/dialog/open-sp-dialog.js"></script>
<!--END Scripts for O365-->

<script>
  $pnp.setup({
    baseUrl: "https://fh126cloud.sharepoint.com/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training"
  });

  $pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("O365RoadMap").items.get().then(function(z) {
    console.log(z);
    var result = z.results.map(a => ({
      Title: `${a.Title}`,
      Description: `${a.Description}`,
      Link: `${a.Link}`
    }))
    console.log(result);
    document.getElementById("roadMap").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result, null, 2)
  })
</script>

<html lang="en">

<body>

  <div>
    /* Code goes here */
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: So you need to create elements and set the text?

Comment: I just need to output the Title, Description and Link Javascript Objects into an HTML template

Comment: So what is the issue with it?  `var html = \`<h1>${a.title}</h1>\``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you are using jQuery so I will answer relative to it.

Using `jQuery` you can put text wherever you want using the [`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method.

For example, if you want to put the `Title` data in your div you could do:

```
$("div").text(result.Title);
```

The code above will place  `result.Title` in every `div` on the page (which you only have one of.).

There are so many `jQuery` methods you could use as-well, such as [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/), [`prepend`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/), and [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/). Append will put the text after the existing content of an element. Prepend puts the text before existing content of an element. Html with replace the html inside of an element.

So if you wanted to construct the HTML elements then place them on the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction) (the web page) you could do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var head = '<h1>${result.Title}</h1>';
    var desc = '<p>${result.Description}</p>'; 
    var link = '<a src="${result.Link}">${result.Link}</a>';
    $("div").html(head + desc + link);
});
```

To put your `Title`, `Description`, and `Link` on the DOM. Hope this help you, good luck!